# Ubuntu Hard Disk Filled up one day, empty the next day

Tags: hard-drive

This is bizarre to me and any insight is welcome. I encountered an issue on our Ubuntu (11.04) server where I kept receiving reports that the hard was completely full (1TB). Running the disk analyzer, it did seem that indeed the entire disk was occupied. This was very strange since it is a relatively new machine with only a few applications. Before I could check anything further the server crashed and I had to reboot the machine several (7+ times) before it started successfully. Once it restarted everything seemed ok, and best of all the disk usage only reported 5GB being used (instead of 1TB).

Given the symptoms above, any ideas as to the possible causes, or anything I should check for, is very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: More details on what apps/processes are running on the server would be helpful, as well as what you found when examining the disk contents prior to the reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't worry** it should be just a case.
The possible causes can be:

- the use of a **SysRq** special key combination.
- an Hard Disk problem (if you enabled the **S.M.A.R.T.** support in your BIOS and you have the proper **S.M.A.R.T**. support software installed).
- a **Kernel Panic** or a "*freeze*".
- a **support system fault** (if the current goes away for a moment and you don't have a charged support group active).
- a **bug**/special feature in a kernel modules.

Anyway, if there is no data loss you can ignore the problem, because it's caused for sure by the partition set as unmounted for the reasons on top (a partition usually gets unmounted automatically to prevent data loss, it's a good thing).
The boot script can remount an unmounted partition.
If you experience the problems another time, please let us know.
Have a nice experience.